# how to open the dict like csv document in Python

Tags: python, pandas

[image]So the problem is that it is a csv file and when I open it with pandas, it looks like this:

```
data=pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', usecols=['properties'])
data.head()[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

It is like a dictionary in each row, just confused how to open it correctly with gender, document_type, etc as columns

{'gender': 'Male', 'nationality': 'IRL', 'document_type': 'passport', 'date_of_expiry': '2019-08-12', 'issuing_country': 'IRL'}

{'gender': 'Female', 'document_type': 'driving_licence', 'date_of_expiry': '2023-02-28', 'issuing_country': 'GBR'}

{'gender': 'Male', 'nationality': 'ITA', 'document_type': 'passport', 'date_of_expiry': '2018-06-09', 'issuing_country': 'ITA'}

[image]

Comment: Please paste the content of first few rows of "test.csv" file in your question. That will help.

Comment: how did such a thing come to be? In any case, that is going to be just text.

Comment: Hi Supratim, thank you. Just posted.

Comment: it seems to be that once an item is missing, the latter will occupy the place... tricky

Comment: Hi Juanpa, do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the cvs file is not properly formated to be read by the default funtion from pandas. You will need to create the columns your self.

```
data['gender'] = data['properties'].str[0].str['gender']
```

For each one of the fields in the dictionary you have.

If there are too many columns, you should consider evaluating the string. like this

```
import ast
my_dict = ast.literal_eval(df.loc[0]['properties') 

for key in my_dict.keys():
    data[key] = data['properties'].str[0].str[key]
```

This should build your DataFrame just fine

Comment: Hi Jose, the data['properties'].str[0] actually have the output of the series of "{" .

Comment: that is the idea, so you can turn that into a dict, is it not working?